# Formatting text file loaded by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I have a panel that's loading a flat file text chat log from a server at run time that updates every second in the browser.  It looks like this:

/chat/Chat_yyyy-mm-dd.log

```
23:25:10 : Global: Colin Fox: testing
23:25:19 : Direct: Colin Fox: testing
23:25:23 : Direct: Martinez Soto: test
23:25:29 : Global: Martinez Soto: test
```

Now, I have a text box in the page that the JS is loading the text file into:

```
<textarea name="globeChat" id="globeChat" cols="50" rows="8" class="form-control" style="resize:none" readonly>No messages to display!</textarea>
```

And finally the Javascript doing the work:

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var file = '/chat/Chat_'+year+'-'+
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '')+month+'-'+
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '')+day+'.log';
    $(function chatText(){
        $.ajax({
            url : file,
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data){
                $("#globeChat").html(data);
            }
        });
        $("#globeChat").scrollTop($("#globeChat")[0].scrollHeight);
        setTimeout(chatText, 1000);
    })();
</script>
```

Now, the next thing I want to accomplish is formatting the text on the page.  Is there any way to do this with a regex or something?  like have the date in dark grey, the channels a specific colour based on channel name (IE, red for global and blue for direct), then the user name would be whatever colour followed by black text for the message.  so it would look something like:

```
<b>23:25:10</b>  <i>Global</i>  <u>Colin Fox</u>: testing
```

And then I can just format #globeChat b, #globeChat i, and #globeChat u however I want using CSS.

I know how to do this with PHP by reading the file into an array and spitting it out with formatted HTML using a regex and a loop.  But how do I do it at run time every second (I'm fine with making it 5 or something if I need to) using javascript/Jquery?

EDIT:

Since none of it is working, I ended up creating a chat.php page instead.  And have a $_GET defining the day offset, and made it so it includes the file and formats it in the chat.php instead and then filled the div with the chat.php:

```
<script>
    var file = "chat.php";
    $(function chatText() {
        $.ajax({
            url: file,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                $("#todayChat").html(response);
            }
        })
        setTimeout(chatText, 1000);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: If you know how to do it with PHP using explode, just use the same logic. javascript's String.split() is the same thing as php's explode().

Comment: ok, so split the file into an array by new lines, then split each line into an array and then loop through each of those to format and print it to the screen?  Sound about right?

Comment: because in PHP i would load the file into an object, then explode that object into an array based on \n, then take that array and regex it into an associative array, then loop the array into an echo or whatever to format it

Comment: yep, sounds about right. `var lines = filecontents.split("\n"); for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){ var chunks = lines[i].split(" "); var formattedLine = "<span style='color:red'>"+chunk[0]+"</span> <span style='color:blue'>"+chunk[1]+"</span>";}`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `.text()`, `.split()` with `RegExp`s `/\b\n[^$]/` , `/\:(?=\s)/`; `$.each()` , `switch()`

```js
var body = $("body");

$("textarea").text(function(_, text) {
  var arr = text.split(/\b\n[^$]/);
   $.each(arr, function(key, line) {
    var l = line.split(/\:(?=\s)/);
    $.each(l, function(index, el) {
      switch(index) {
        case 0: body.append("<b>" + el +"</b>"); break; 
        case 1: body.append("<i>" + el + "</i>"); break;
        case 2: body.append("<u>" + el + "</u>:"); break;
        case 3: body.append(el + "<br>"); break;
      }
    })
  });
  return text
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
<textarea>
23:25:10 : Global: Colin Fox: testing
23:25:19 : Direct: Colin Fox: testing
23:25:23 : Direct: Martinez Soto: test
23:25:29 : Global: Martinez Soto: test
</textarea><br>
</body>
```

---

> so im messing with it and I can't figure how to load the file into the
>   function and write to the textarea rather than write from the textarea
>   to the object.

Note, it is not possible to style `<b>` , `<i>` , `<u>` elements within a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element. The `value` of a `textarea` text , not rendered `html` elements.

You could substitute a `<div>` element with `contentEditable` attribute for `textarea` element to render `b`, `i`, `u` elements within a container where the text can be edited by the user.

The updated `success` function is not the same as using `.text()` parameters. `data` is the returned response text to parse at `$.ajax()` `success`; the second parameter at `success` is `textStatus`.

You should be able to adjust `html` and `js` to achieve expected results

html

```
<div id="globeChat" contentEditable>
</div>
```

css

```
div[contentEditable] {
  border:1px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

js

```
$(function chatText() {
  $.ajax({
      url: file,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {       
        var arr = data.split(/\b\n[^$]/);
        console.log(arr, data);
        $.each(arr, function(key, line) {
            var l = line.split(/\:(?=\s)/);
            $.each(l, function(index, el) {
                switch (index) {
                  case 0:
                    strTxt += "<b>" + el + "</b>";
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    strTxt += "<i>" + el + "</i>";
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    strTxt += "<u>" + el + "</u>:";
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    strTxt += el + "<br>";
                    break;
                };
            });
        });
      $("#globeChat").html(strTxt).focus();
      return data;
    }
  })
});
```

```js
var strTxt = "";
var data = "23:25:10 : Global: Colin Fox: testing\n" + "23:25:19 : Direct: Colin Fox: testing\n" + "23:25:23 : Direct: Martinez Soto: test\n" + "23:25:29 : Global: Martinez Soto: test";

var arr = data.split(/\b\n[^$]/);
console.log(arr, data);
$.each(arr, function(key, line) {
  var l = line.split(/\:(?=\s)/);
  $.each(l, function(index, el) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        strTxt += "<b>" + el + "</b>";
        break;
      case 1:
        strTxt += "<i>" + el + "</i>";
        break;
      case 2:
        strTxt += "<u>" + el + "</u>:";
        break;
      case 3:
        strTxt += el + "<br>";
        break;
    };
  });
});
$("#globeChat").html(strTxt).focus();
```

```css
div[contentEditable] {
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="globeChat" contentEditable>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ffvpuhe4/

Comment: I think this may work except I need to have it write from the file to the textarea

Comment: so im messing with it and I can't figure how to load the file into the function and write to the textarea rather than write from the textarea to the object.

Comment: @Flynn It is not possible to render `b`, `i`, `u` elements with a `textarea` element; you could substitute `div` with `contentEditable` attribute for `textarea` element. See updated post